# Let us finally retract flags on comments

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags, comments

We have had the ability to retract flags on posts [for a while now](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/281010/253521) (Meta.SE link). However, this ability does not extend to comment flags. This is unfortunate, because I recently flagged a comment and then realized my flag was incorrect.

Also unfortunately, the Help Center page [discussing this privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) makes no mention of such limitations, the reason for which is also mentioned in the above Meta.SE answer.

Seeing as how this problem can actually occur, and it seems not to be a ton of effort to enable it for comments, can we please extend the ability to retract flags to comments?

Comment: As long as you're not doing lots of these erroneous flaggings, I'm not sure what retracting it would get you.  Yes, you can have your flag declined and have it count against you, but if it's not *a lot* of them, there really shouldn't be an issue.  Could you explain a slightly better rationale for it?

Comment: @Makoto It would get me the ability to help avoid unnecessary work for our brave moderators. The rationale is already fine, I think: there's an ability that exists, except for this subcase. The subcase *happens*, therefore the ability should cover it. If the devs want to come in and say "well it would actually be quite a heavy load here for only a small percentage of times", that's fine, and is *their* prerogative.

Comment: @Makoto Of course, it's going to be very hard for them to show real (or even stipulated) statistics for "cases where a user erroneously flagged a comment and wanted/tried to remove it". At best they could show numbers for how many times mods have been manually contacted by users about their erroneous flag.

Comment: A conjecture to that would be, of the people that have flagged incorrectly, how many would *actually* retract this and go about this the right way?  I can be convinced that this is useful, we just need a way to determine how useful it really will be.  Dev time ain't cheap.

Comment: @Makoto I agree that it's not cheap, but the dev who wrote the answer on Meta.SE worded it in such a way that it seemed... trivial... perhaps, that it was not turned on for comments. At any rate, it's a dev's decision that's needed.

Comment: It'll be really hard to get data on how often this would be used, don't expect anything useful. We usually blitz the comment flags at light speed; they don't get any more attention than they deserve as third-class citizens. Definitely agree that this would be good to have for consistency. Hopefully it's a small enough amount of dev time that it can just be done.

Comment: An additional aspect to consider is that the third-class-citizen status of comments implies that some mods delete whatever gets flagged, without invoking higher-level cognitive processes (at least this is my impression). A mistaken flag on a comment might lead to its unmerited deletion, which could've been prevented by a retracted flag.

Comment: Cross site duplicate https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/285003/228134

Comment: It's not *that* bad @AndrasDeak - we actually read them, but we don't dig into context and probably won't catch subtle issues like we might with posts.  Pretty sure no one is robotically deleting all the flagged comments, otherwise we'd just automate it and wouldn't have any comment flags.

Comment: @Undo I know _you_ do;) And most of you do. (I don't actually _know_ that any of you _don't_, I just vaguely remember some hints on meta that some mods don't think twice about deleting comments. Might be irrelevant/unfounded. I rarely flag comments so I wouldn't know either way.)

Comment: @Undo If ***Q-A*** comments are *third-class citizens*, what in holy existence are ***chat*** comments?

Comment: @SeldomNeedy Chat isn't really a collection of comments, it's just conversations.

Comment: @TylerH Tell that to everyone whose "comments have been moved to chat." ;)

Comment: @SeldomNeedy Yeah, "converted to chat" would be better verbiage for what is going on there.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Happy to announce that ability to retract a comment flag is now live network-wide. If you can flag a comment, then you can retract that flag.

It works in a similar way to post flag retractions - click on the activated flag, and confirm in the resulting modal that you would like to retract the flag. Note: you cannot reflag the same flag on the same comment after retracting it - unless it is a custom flag, in which case you are allowed to reflag it.

Comment: _"Note: you cannot reflag the same flag on the same comment after retracting it."_ But we can apply other flags? So we can fix the mistakes our fat fingers make (which we take no responsibility for)?

Comment: Yes, you can apply other flags, just not the same one.

Comment: Thank you, for implementing a feature requested by the  community.

Comment: Did you also remove the flag hover effect on purpose, or is that a bug? (guessing that's related to this, as the problem appeared after this was pushed)