# Can I retract a flag on a comment?

Tags: support, comment-flags

I have mistakenly flagged a comment and now I want to retract it.

Is it possible to retract the flag from the comment?

Comment: No. See feature request here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351632/let-us-finally-retract-flags-on-comments

Comment: after how many time this feature will available?

Comment: [6 to 8 weeks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/19514)

Comment: This is not possible, right now. Feel free to chime in on the feature request asking for the ability to retract comments.