# Should a comment flag be removed if the comment is edited?

Tags: discussion, flags, comments

Earlier today I [flagged a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47075615/objective-c-how-to-create-self-view-inside-safe-area-programmatically/47075749#comment81108078_47075749) as being rude/abusive. Shortly after I had raised the flag, the comment was edited to something more paletable, which was no longer worthy of a flag. However, given that [comment flags are currently not retractable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351632/let-us-finally-retract-flags-on-comments), I inevitably received a decline against the flag.

While I personally can take the hit of one decline every once in a while, this raises an interesting question for those that may be near a flag ban threshold. If a comment is initially flag-worthy when raised, but is then edited to fall back in line, should existing flags against be cancelled?

The obvious problem with this is that those who are genuinely being abusive can make a trivial edit to cancel any flags against them, so the balance of keeping the site clean vs negatively affecting genuine flaggers has to be kept in mind. However, the flipside is that a flagger caught out by this may get an unwarranted flag ban.

As a side question, are those reviewing the flags shown the comment in question *at current the revision when the flag was raised*, or the current up-to-date revision?

Comment: AFAIK - comment flags don't contribute towards flag bans.

Comment: I didn't handle that flag, but looking at the revisions - not quite sure why you flagged it as rude/abusive?

Comment: @JonClements Can you post the original text to refresh my memory? While it's not the worst I came across today, I do remember it still being fairly terse.

Comment: @MichaelDodd Terse is not rude or abusive, or a reason to flag at all.

Comment: Fair enough, may have been a genuine decline or a borderline one then.

Comment: @JonClements Didn't I read once that edited comments still leave trails? I'm pretty sure I saw something about that not too long ago.

Comment: It would probably be enough to make comment flags retractable. Also, I'm not sure the problem with your suggestion that abusive users would edit their comment just to clear the flags would be such a big problem since they are only allowed to edit their comments within 5 minutes. Yes, they could clear the flags within those 5 minutes, but if their comment is abusive, it would be flagged again after 5 minutes when the author of the comment no longer has the possibility to edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not the inherent problem with comment flags. If you flag a comment within the little time the author has to edit it, then you're faster than I've ever been. The real problem is the interface for moderators; they only get 2 choices:

1. Delete the comment, rendering the flag Helpful.
2. Decline the flag.

> As a side question, are those reviewing the flags shown the comment in question *at current the revision when the flag was raised*, or the current up-to-date revision?

I've never actually seen the mod interface, but I'd guess the latter is correct. I'm shown the current revision in all review queues; why would it be different here?

Comment: I find it interesting that, if this is the case, there's no neutral "disputed" decision similar to on question or answer flags.

Comment: @MichaelDodd and that's most of the problem.

Comment: @Michael We have three options; "delete": which marks the flag as helpful, "dismiss": which effectively declines the flag, or "edit" - and that's hardly used - mostly for comments where 99% of it is good and we can just take out a sentence that's no so. As a moderator I've only found it useful (looks at dashboard) 9 times in 2.5 years

Comment: But yes... Comment flags we really don't have a way of getting back to you as to why.

Comment: *"If you flag a comment within the little time the author has to edit it, then you're faster than I've ever been."* If you start watching the [Heat Detector](https://stackapps.com/q/7001/46701), you can be that fast all day. :)

Comment: @Baum mit Augen and that's where I found said comment in the first place :)