# Flagging content, and then it's edited

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags

Here is a better duplicate that was just answered too.
[Let us finally retract flags on comments](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/351632/let-us-finally-retract-flags-on-comments)

---

I'm not sure if this is a question, a discussion, a complaint or a feature request.

The issue I have had is that when you flag a post, depending on the type you can't retract it.
If you flag a question and answer then you can retract it, but comments are locked in.
It may sound, like "big deal", but the comments can be edited to make your flag incorrect.

This has happened twice to me now, once on an answer where the answer was low quality (if I remember correctly) and I flagged it.
Noticed my flag was disputed and looked at the answer again and it has been edited to a better answer. So the dispute is correct, but so *was* my flag but I didn't know the post was edited and didn't have a chance to retract my flag.

Same thing happened on a comment, a comment was posted in a foreign language and I flagged it.
Then a minute or so later the comment was translated to English.
So I figured I would retract my flag, but that is not possible.
I got a helpful mark on the flag which is actually incorrect, but I suppose the previous edit was noted.

> (Since someone will ask I might as well answer it now, why didn't you just ask/tell the commenter to post in English?
>   Don't know, I recall the user as having a higher rep. Not high, but not new.
>   I can't explain why, it just happened.

As far as I know, there are enough flags that is correct, so if we can minimize the number of flags that is incorrect that would be a good thing.
Right?

First off why isn't flags retractable on comments?
And perhaps the flagger should be noted with a message when a flagged content is edited so that he/she can retract an unnecessary flag?

Comment: Realistically if you try to keep spotless flagging history you should wait for 5 minutes before flagging comments... and only flag 100% clear cut cases... I'm not really sure if "minimize the number of flags that is incorrect" is really good thing if that requires manually tracking each flag one rises... Hopefully some moderators will chime in to say if this is actually a  problem.

Comment: But that still doesn't solve the problem on questions and answers, they can be edited after 5 minutes

Comment: Just wait longer :)... Most posts are abandoned after a day at most... (Side note: you may think about what  your FR is actually trying to solve - so far posts reads for me as you trying to help with your personal accept/decline ratio and not something useful for the site like moderators' load)

Comment: Isn't that a win-win? If I lighten the load for moderators and reviews and get a better ration. What is the downside? Why do you think this would be a bad thing? If we all wait with flagging then there is more "crap" piling up. Would you go back to a question x days ago and flag it because it was posted in Spanish?

Comment: People only typically look at *declined* flags - disputed and aged away flags don't count towards, e.g. flag bans or helpful flag percentages (e.g. [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380988/1364007)).

Comment: @Andreas if such change encourages people to spend significant amount of time monitoring they flags I think it is loss-loss - less time left to looking at new content and hence more chances of flags being handled by community and not moderators...

Comment: @WaiHaLee good find. But in my opinion not complete duplicate (I see you also edited your comment to indicate so). I'm actually not to concerned about any percentage or ratio of my flags. What is bugging me is the *"Your last flag was **declined**, are you sure this is correct"*. It's kind of annoying to read when your flag *was* correct at the time you flagged.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov you really think it's that often you flag something and then the content is changed enough to make you want to retract the flag? Either way it's up to you, if you want to click the message and read it or not. If you do, you get a chance to possibly correct yourself, if you don't you get the same result as today.

Comment: I really dislike the suggested trend here, of *'waiting for the post to die down'* so your flag acceptance rate can't be afflicted by an edit. That's something that should be improved for the sake of the quality of the content and not avoided for artificial reasons

Comment: @Rawrplus agree. Flagging should be done as soon as possible in order to keep the site clean and give immediate feedback (or at least as soon as possible) to the person who wrote the unneeded/rude/offensive comment. If we all wait a couple of days just to make sure it has all settled then we will display something that is not ok on SO, but only take care of it a couple of days later. This will the commenter and other viewers confused.

Comment: Obviously the problem is it's hard to get things implemented for the company... The linked question is [status-deferred]. // Side note: the commenter is usually not notified when their comment is deleted (unless the moderator send a custom message)

Comment: [Should a comment flag be removed if the comment is edited? - Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358798/should-a-comment-flag-be-removed-if-the-comment-is-edited) ;; https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314492/editing-of-comment-after-flagging

Comment: @user202729 *Side note: the commenter is usually not notified when their comment is deleted (unless the moderator send a custom message)*. True! But if the comment is deleted "soon" then the person who wrote the comment may notice his/her was deleted. And it also deletes a offending/incorrect/wrong/unneeded comment showing the level that is expected. Keeping it on the site makes people think that is an accepted comment.

Comment: "so if we can minimize the number of flags that is incorrect that would be a good thing. Right?"  Yes. Agree. I'd like the flag to be set only if the writer of the comment agrees with the flag.

Comment: I think this could be a feature request: Request that flags are marked as "helpful" if they were helpful at the time they were given, or some sort of special action if the content in question gets edited before the flag can get handled.

Comment: Fwiw, on posts I usually check the revision history and mark the flag helpful/declined based on the state of the post at the time, and then take action based on the current state (plus history, where it matters). Though if you flag during the grace period and don't leave a comment to break it, that is not possible.

Comment: As Baum said, in the first minutes, you don't see the history of the post. So it can be "stealth edited" to remove bad content. But is that so frequent? It's more used to copy other answers and pretend to be the first to have found the solution...

Comment: That said, moderators are rather swift to handle rude/abusive flags or spam both on comments & posts, so the editor will have to be quick to avoid being caught... also note that if a really offensive word is in a comment, the flag is automatically accepted and the comment deleted.

Answer (score 44):

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)

I think the comment section here reveals a worrying trend. where users suggest rather waiting for the activity to die down so an edit is less likely and hence your flag less likely to be ruled obsolete *(and incorrect)* by an edit. In my opinion, this goes against the very philosophy of SO, where we are supposed to provide quality questions and quality answers.

The site should be kept clean and the fact **the immediate feedback is arbitrary delayed** in an offchance, that somebody might edit their content later hints, that there might be something wrong with the system.

I think the current flag review queue should be ammended, like so, where the information would be carried over whether the question/answer has been edited after the flag.

- **Perhaps create a separate queue / edit the current queue**, with slightly edited options. Where if the flag was declined after the edit it would not have negative impact on the person who raised the flag

[image]

*(picture only illustrative)*

Technically, this would raise a small issue, where a properly declined flag would not 'punish' the user. But overall, I think the approach of SO should be **to encourage the usage of already under-manned review queues and not seek further ways to discourage users from doing them**.  I for one would rather have one incorrect flag go unpunished, rather than have a completely bad question/answer go unnoticed!

Comment: It's also crazy to think that I should wait until later because I don't have a mechanism to keep track of crappy posts.  If I wait until later, I'll lose them.

Comment: @zero298 I agree. For example, if I downvote an answer, I tend to go back to it to check if it's been edited to a more acceptable level and then remove the downvote. But it's impossible to keep track of something I've *not* flagged or cast a vote on. I suppose unless I bookmark each individual comment/post. But I'd also need the time when I've seen it, so I can go to anything that's more than 24 hours old. And I'd need to share this across devices. I'd need an entire spreadsheet or even a separate system just to manage my flags. No thanks.

Comment: @VLAZ bookmarks on one device usually transfers to other devices too. At least chrome does. But that does not make it any more practical. It's still better to flag at first sight.

Comment: @Andreas I use different Firefox sync profiles on some devices, so that doesn't actually help me. And again, I'd also have to keep track of what was bookmarked *when* and only come back to a bookmark when sufficient time has elapsed. I can easily encounter 10+ flaggable items in a day, so it does become a huge hassle to work around the flagging system in order to flag stuff with delay.

Comment: @VLAZ That is such a hassle that I doubt 99% of the userbase would bother doing it.  Also, it sounds silly to continuously check and keep track of everything you downvoted or flagged. Imho it's just a robust workout around something that should not be an issue in a first place

Comment: @Rawrplus I check my downvotes for a reasonable amount of time. About 24 hours, assuming the author appears to be active. Maybe if something was posted on a Friday, I'd check it on a Monday. I don't tend to be very active over the weekend anyway. About a day seems reasonable to address any problems with a post. If an author is not active, then I don't keep checking forever as they might not even log in again. I think that's rather fair - after all, a downvote signifies an answer is not useful. If that changes, then the downvote seems hardly warranted.

Comment: @VLAZ Don't get me wrong, I commend your dedication, in fact I'm impressed. My point is. you are rather the exception of the norm