# Why can't you retract NAA flags after author-edit?

Tags: support, declined-flags, not-an-answer, retracted-flags

One of my recent flags was an NAA and was declined because "the moderator found no evidence to support...", but the answer was edited by the author much later to add context to their drive-by "comment answer".

Since the answer was edited by the original author, my NAA flag persisted and the moderator declined it. I'm now locked out of raising flags because that was my third declined flag in 7 days.

My question:

**Why can't we retract our own NAA flags after the original author edits their answer?**

Why do I not get to have any control over the situation?

Since it's being requested, here's [the answer I flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69020147/revisions) as NAA.

I was really hoping this wouldn't turn into a discussion about whether my NAA flag was justified.

Comment: is it possible the drive by "comment answer" was in fact an answer? an incomplete, short, or unclear answer, even wrong answers or answers to unrelated questions, are still considered "answers". Only things that are blatantly *not* answers are not answers, such as "I have this problem too!" or gibberish/thanks etc.

Comment: "Why can't we un-raise our own NAA flags after the original author edits their answer?" - you can, but it requires you to actually do it before it's handled. When it's handled, you can't retract it.

Comment: You can retract NAA flags. A single decline because an answer was improved after you flagged shouldn’t be problem. Three declines in a short period, on the other hand, would. But all three declines happening because of edits invalidating the flag would be **very** unlucky.

Comment: @Zoe well that's insane. How am I supposed to know something was edited hours or days later? Why is it my responsibility to lord over somebody else's answer? It sounds like you're saying I essentially need to try to *slip back in after the author edits their answer and before the moderator reviews my flag*?

Comment: This is where the "follow" feature may help since the followers will be notified when the post is edited.

Comment: mods tend to look out for edited posts, so there are two possibilities: (A) your flag would've been declined either way; (B) much less likely - the handling mod failed to notice that the post has been edited since the flag. In any case, a link to the post in question would be helpful.

Comment: @OlegValter I was hoping to avoid this turning into a "why was my NAA flag declined" discussion. I don't want the focus to be on the flag or the answer itself because that's not what I was asking about. Happy to oblige, but I'd prefer not to.

Comment: Worth reading: [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/241919)

Comment: That was an attempt at answering the question, so the NAA flag was rightfully declined. See [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11682469). NAA flags are often handled in bulk and so are only for posts that obviously don't attempt to answer a suitable question (eg. "I have the same problem. Did you find a solution?", "Thanks to Jeanne! Your answer solved my problem!")

Comment: @AndrewT. fair enough. I disagree with the idea that I'm responsible for watching an answer I flagged (we all have lives outside of SO), but I'll keep it in mind for next time.

Comment: Actually, it has become better. Nowadays mods can see if an answer was edited and can see the revision that was flagged. So a NAA flag maybe marked helpful but the answer remain after being edited into an actual answer. But in your case the version you flagged was already not an NAA.

Comment: There seem to be a lot of caveats and unspoken rules and meta in regards to the flagging system. At this point I'm just venting my frustration.

Comment: @Zoe does your first comment work as an answer? I'd like to close this question and don't know if it's useful enough to keep on Meta, or if I should just delete it.

Comment: Nah , it's ok (as you can see, the original answer is also material for the discussion at hand) - vent off some steam, take a break and come back if you still want to help poor mods out in the neverending quest of handling the flood of garbage posts.

Comment: "How am I supposed to know something was edited hours or days later?" - you can keep an eye on it, [piggyback on GenericBot](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/111347/sobotics), or follow the post, which is a thing now and notifies you if the post has been edited. "Why is it my responsibility to lord over somebody else's answer? It sounds like you're saying I essentially need to try to slip back in after the author edits their answer and before the moderator reviews my flag?" - some mods dispute flags on posts that were edited into shape, but others don't. (1/2)

Comment: There's no particular consensus on how those flags are meant to be handled, but it's more common for them to be disputed than declined, at least with the "regular" flag reviewers (regular in this context being the mods who review these flags frequently). That said, depending on what you flag, it may or may not be a problem. If you flag NAAs to old questions, the edit rate is so obscenely low that you could probably automatically flag every post that gets tp feedback, and basically never need to retract. If you're flagging stuff from active users, though, you'll generally need to keep a (2/3)

Comment: closer eye on the posts, because there's a decent chance an edit invalidates your flag. Of course, a few of these things assume it was clearly and undisputably NAA in the first place - if it wasn't, that's a different story. And while my first comment does work as an answer, I've been ninja'd while eating, but seems the point got across. But I hope you keep flagging when your ban is lifted - wanting to learn is a good sign at least

Comment: Your flag was declined prior to the recorded edit on that answer (i.e. the moderator evaluated your flag based on the revision which you flagged). [Note: That's not, necessarily, accurate. When you flagged, 27 seconds remained of the 5 minute edit grace period, so it's *possible* what you flagged wasn't the version which remains in the record as the first revision. No record is available in the SE database of any version which was replaced during the grace period, so there's no way for us to know (SE devs *could* look at the server logs, but don't for this type of issue).]

Comment: @Zoe Moderators can't directly dispute any flags other than spam and rude/abusive. We *might* be able to do so for those flags which are disputed as a result of reviews in the review queues by participating in those reviews, but there's no direct mechanism for us to do so (other than spam and rude/abusive flags). For spam and rude/abusive, flags we can only dispute *all* spam and rude/abusive flags currently existing on the post, regardless of their current state (i.e. helpful, declined, and retracted), or none of them.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Why can't we un-raise our own NAA flags after the original author edits their answer?

You can [retract](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/351632/11682469) your NAA flag *until* it was reviewed. An edit to the post makes no difference (note that this is different for VLQ flags that are marked helpful after an edit after the grace period).

So the reviewing and the fact that other volunteers already had to and did spend time reviewing your flag is decisive. At that moment the flag was handled and can't be retracted anymore.

Nowadays mods also see a [notification](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/387362/11682469) that the post was edited and can then see the revision you flagged. Even if the post was edited into an answer, your flag may then still be marked helpful.

In your case, even the revision you flagged as NAA was an attempt at answering the question and so declining it was the correct action. See [When to flag an answer as "not an answer"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/11682469).

Comment: I guess my confusion comes from the actual description of the flag: "This was posted as an answer, but it does not attempt to answer the question. It should possibly be an edit, **a comment,** another question, or deleted altogether." Emphasis mine. I interpreted that liberally. I tend to associate answers that give details and code as answers, and "hints" as something more appropriate for comments.

Comment: With regards to comments, see the [use cases for posting comments](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) to get an idea what kind of answer might be converted to a comment.

Comment: @blorgon The key part of what you've quoted which you are not putting enough emphasis on is "but it does not *attempt* to answer the question". The answer which you linked in your question was an attempt to answer, even in [the revision that you flagged](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69020147/1). It wasn't a *good* answer, but it was an attempt to answer, and thus not NAA. [Note: NAA flags are actually interpreted slightly differently. Rather than "attempt to answer *the* question", it's really interpreted closer to "attempt to answer *a* question which might be on-topic".]